# HLS Streaming seekto not working on android 3.0+

Tags: android, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I have problem seeking into live hls stream.

When I call getCurrentPosition on videoview it returns 40 000, but when I try to seekto(20000); nothing changes, no error no action.

so if anyone has any suggestions please help me.

here is an code example:

```
//video is playing live 
seek = 20000;
if(_vPlayer.getCurrentPosition() > seek) {
    _vPlayer.seekTo(seek);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that seek is not supported for HLS (see also http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) where they state that, for H-264 AVC, they support MPEG-TS (AAC audio only, not seekable, Android 3.0+)

When I try [this stream](http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8) on a Galaxay SII, the native player doesn't support seeking either.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019564/hls-http-live-streaming-on-android-3-0-and-seeking?rq=1) for a better/more complete answer

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:
1) Try implementing OnSeekCompleteListener to determine if the seek is actually completing successfully:
[VideoView not playing Video from desired position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990784/videoview-not-playing-video-from-desired-position/11938019#11938019)

2) Try pause, seekTo, start. Again, you'll probably need to implement OnSeekCompleteListener; or for testing purposed just sleep for a bit in between seekTo and start.