# How to play .m3u8 video url on Android Device?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, video-streaming

I have a requirement to play .m3u8 video url on Andriod Device 
I am trying to execute below Code,But it is not working,I'm getting Video Can't be played?

Could any one help?

SourceCode:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.app.Activity;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            VideoView vw = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
            vw.setVideoPath(".m3u8 URL Here");
            vw.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
            vw.requestFocus();
            vw.start();
    }
}
```

**Note:**

I have Followed this link [HLS (http live streaming) on Android 3.0 and seeking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019564/hls-http-live-streaming-on-android-3-0-and-seeking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a library todo this, i recommend you to use Vitamio it is very powerful Chinese library works for 2.1+ devices, check it in Github in "English"

https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle