# Android: seek HLS DVR stream

Tags: android, streaming, media-player, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to seek (rewind) a DVR HLS Stream using a MediaPlayer object, but I'm getting th errors:

```
01-20 11:43:02.214: E/MediaPlayerService(296): getDuration returned -2147483648
01-20 11:43:02.214: W/MediaPlayer(30590): Stream has no duration and is therefore not seekable.
```

I have read the previous questions, ( [HLS (http live streaming) on Android 3.0 and seeking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019564/hls-http-live-streaming-on-android-3-0-and-seeking) ) but they are 2 years old.

Has there been any progress on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

HLS streams are nothing but MPEG-TS format streams. These streams can be played but are not seekable on Android (http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

That being said, there has been progress with the playback of HLS content on Android. The NuPlayer which is the default media player (5.1.1 onwards) support HLS streaming. The content is seekable as well. The only issue that I observe is that video frame rendering is bit lagging. It appears as if the media player is dropping too many video frames in order to be in sync with the audio playback.